# Topology: an exercise on a set

Tags: general-topology

I have this set:

$$X=\left\{1+\frac{1}{x}: x\in \Bbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\} \right\}\,\cup\, \Bbb Z\, \cup \, ]-5,-4[$$

There are five options, and I'm helping to find for a student the **true** answer:

1. $\operatorname{Fr}X=\partial X$ and a limited set on the upper side;
2. $\overset{\circ}{X}$ is a finite set;
3. $X$ is not closed set;
4. $D(DX) \neq DX$;
5. $X$ has not internal points.

I try to think a little bit in terms of exclusion. An isolated point is always a frontier point and since Z, it has infinite cardinality and is made of all isolated points cannot be the $(1)$. The $(5)\simeq (2)$ no because between $]-5,-4[$ I have infinity internal points. I didn't try the $(4)$. But it seems to me that it's the $(3)$ true because there is the almost the set $]-5,-4[$ that is open.

I am helping a student of an Italian University. Please correct me if I'm in error. But I can't seem to tackle $(4)$.

This is the original screenshot of the exam-text:

[image]

Comment: Why must **you** find *for a student* the answers?

Comment: @amWhy If you see some of my previous questions and comments you will note that I am helping a student registered in Economics and Finance. I don't remember much about topology.

Comment: If you are tutoring the student, I'd prefer you'd have asked "I am working to be of greatest a help to the student as I can be.  It's been awhile since I've studied topology, but I'm pretty sure [blah, blah, blah].  Please correct me if I'm in error.  But I can't seem to tackle (4)."  The way you phrased your sentence makes it sound that you are being paid to do a students homework for them.  I just wanted clarification.  Thank you for that.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not very good to write in English language :-( I hope it's a bit better now. If not can you improved it, please?

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, @Sebastiano.  All in all, you do quite a fine job writing English :-)

Comment: @amWhy My head is fused :-( Thank you very much for your contribute.

Comment: Is $D(X)$  the set of limit points of $X$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $DX$  is the set of accumulation points of $X$. I have now added the original screenshot. This teacher not put the rounded brackets.

Comment: @Sebastiano: It appears to me that $(3)$ and $(4)$ are both true: if I understand the notation, $DX=\{1\}\cup[-5,-4]$, and $D(DX)=[-5,-4]$. $(1)$ is false, since the boundary of $X$ includes $\Bbb Z$, which is not bounded above.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your reply with an important comment. The $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+1/x)=1$ and $1$ it is an accumulation point like, $-5$ and $-4$. The notation that you have used it is correct. But the answer is one. :-( I'm totally agree with you.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, but why is $X$ not closed? Although $]-5,-4[$ is open, both $-5$ and $-4$ are in $\mathbb Z\subseteq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $$X = \left\{1+\frac1x\mid x \in \Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}\right\} \cup \Bbb  Z \cup ]-5,-4[$$

Then the leftmost part is just $\{\frac12, \frac23, \frac34, \ldots, \frac32, \frac43, \frac54\}$ which is basically two sequences (of isolated points) that both converge to $1$, from the left and the right. The limit and accumulation point $1$ is also in $X$ as part of $\Bbb Z$. The integers are isolated points and we have $[-5,-4]$ as well (the open interval, plus its boundary points also included in $\Bbb Z$. So $X$ can be written as two sequences plus limit, which are closed, unioned with the closed set of the integers and the closed interval.

So $X$ is closed.
Also:  $$\partial X = \left\{ 1+\frac1x \mid x \in \Bbb Z\setminus \{0\}\right\} \cup \Bbb Z$$

$$ \overset{\circ}{X} = ]-5,-4[$$
$$ DX = \{1\} \cup [-5,4]; D(DX) = [-5,-4]$$

So 1 (the boundary is bounded above) is false. $\overset{\circ}{X}$ is infinite, so 2 is false, 3 is false as we saw, 4 is true as they differ by $\{1\}$ and 5 is false (meta remark: it must be as otherwise 2 would also have been true, so even without seeing $X$ we can say 5 is false based on the fact that only *one* answer can be correct).

So 4 is the unique correct answer.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. Just like a first impression, why the 3. is false?

Comment: @Sebastiano I said that $X$ is closed as a union of three closed sets. Or use that $DX \subseteq X$.

Comment:  I not am connected con my mind. 